# After a reboot the DRBD comes up with Connected Diskless/Diskless status

Tags: debian-stretch, proxmox, drbd

After an unattented power loss, facing a major issue, every reboot the **DBRB** comes up with **Connected Diskless/Diskless** status.

**main problems:**

> - dump-md response: Found meta data is "unclean"
> - apply-al command terminated with exit code 20 with message open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
> - drbd resource config cannot be opened exclusive.

**About the environment:**

This drbd resource normaly used as a block storage for lvm, which configured as an (shared lvm) storage to a proxmox ve 5.3-8 cluster. On top of drbd block device an lvm configured, but on drbd host lvm config the device (/dev/nvme0n1p1) below drbd serivice are filtered out (/etc/lvm/lvm.conf shown below)

*The device under drbd is an PCIe NVMe device*

It has some extra properties shown by systemctl:

```
root@pmx0:~# systemctl list-units | grep nvme
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-0000:0c:00.0-nvme-nvme0-nvme0n1-nvme0n1p1.device             loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:0c:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.1-0000:0c:00.0-nvme-nvme0-nvme0n1.device                       loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:0c:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1
```

Other storage device normal SAS disks listing in sytemctl looks a little different:

```
root@pmx0:~# systemctl list-units | grep sdb
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:0b:00.0-host0-target0:2:1-0:2:1:0-block-sdb-sdb1.device loaded active     plugged   PERC_H710 1
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:0b:00.0-host0-target0:2:1-0:2:1:0-block-sdb-sdb2.device loaded active     plugged   PERC_H710 2
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:01.0-0000:0b:00.0-host0-target0:2:1-0:2:1:0-block-sdb.device      loaded active     plugged   PERC_H710
```

list NVMe /sys/devices/.. with ls:

```
root@pmx0:~# ls /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:0c:00.0/nvme/nvme0/nvme0n1/nvme0n1p1
alignment_offset  dev  discard_alignment  holders  inflight  partition  power  ro  size  start  stat  subsystem  trace  uevent
```

**Things are NOT hepls:**

- Reboot again not help
- drbd service restart not help
- drbdadm detach/disconnect/attach/service restart not help
- nfs-kernel-server service aren't confiured on these drbd nodes (so cannot unconfigure nfs-server)

**After some investigation:**

> dump-md response: Found **meta data is "unclean"**, please apply-al first
>   apply-al command terminated with exit code 20 with this message:
>   open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) **failed: Device or resource busy**
>
> It seems that the **problem is that this device** (/dev/nvme0n1p1) used by my
>   drbd resource config **cannot be opened exclusive**.

**Failing DRBD commands:**

```
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm attach r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm apply-al r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20

root@pmx0:~# drbdadm dump-md r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy

Exclusive open failed. Do it anyways?
[need to type 'yes' to confirm] yes

Found meta data is "unclean", please apply-al first
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal dump-md' terminated with exit code 255
```

**DRBD service status/commands:**

```
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Secondary Diskless/Diskless
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm dstate r0
Diskless/Diskless
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm disconnect r0
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  . . .
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm detach r0
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  . . .
```

**Trying reattach resource r0:**

```
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm attach r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm apply-al r0
open(/dev/nvme0n1p1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/nvme0n1p1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
```

**lsof, fuser zero output:**

```
root@pmx0:~# lsof /dev/nvme0n1p1
root@pmx0:~# fuser /dev/nvme0n1p1
root@pmx0:~# fuser /dev/nvme0n1
root@pmx0:~# lsof /dev/nvme0n1
```

**Resource disk partition and LVM config:**

```
root@pmx0:~# fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.9 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x59762e31

Device         Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048 3825207295 3825205248  1.8T 83 Linux
root@pmx0:~# pvs
  PV             VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb2      pve          lvm2 a--  135.62g  16.00g
root@pmx0:~# vgs
  VG           #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  pve            1   3   0 wz--n- 135.62g  16.00g
root@pmx0:~# lvs
  LV            VG           Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data          pve          twi-a-tz--  75.87g             0.00   0.04
  root          pve          -wi-ao----  33.75g
  swap          pve          -wi-ao----   8.00g
root@pmx0:~# vi /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
root@pmx0:~# cat /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep nvm
        filter = [ "r|/dev/nvme0n1p1|", "a|/dev/sdb|", "a|sd.*|", "a|drbd.*|", "r|.*|" ]
```

**DRBD resource config:**

```
root@pmx0:~# cat /etc/drbd.d/r0.res
resource r0 {
        protocol C;
        startup {
                wfc-timeout  0;     # non-zero wfc-timeout can be dangerous (http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/3465-Is-it-safe-to-use-wfc-timeout-in-DRBD-configuration)
                degr-wfc-timeout 300;
        become-primary-on both;
        }
        net {
                cram-hmac-alg sha1;
                shared-secret "*********";
                allow-two-primaries;
                after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
                after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
                after-sb-2pri disconnect;
                #data-integrity-alg crc32c;     # has to be enabled only for test and disabled for production use (check man drbd.conf, section "NOTES ON DATA INTEGRITY")
        }
        on pmx0 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/nvme0n1p1;
                address 10.0.20.15:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on pmx1 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/nvme0n1p1;
                address 10.0.20.16:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        disk {
                # no-disk-barrier and no-disk-flushes should be applied only to systems with non-volatile (battery backed) controller caches.
                # Follow links for more information:
                # http://www.drbd.org/users-guide-8.3/s-throughput-tuning.html#s-tune-disable-barriers
                # http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-throughput-tuning.html#s-tune-disable-barriers
                no-disk-barrier;
                no-disk-flushes;
        }
}
```

**OTHER NODE:**

```
root@pmx1:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Secondary Diskless/Diskless
```

and so on every command responses and configurations showing the same like node pmx0 above...

**Debian and DRBD versions:**

```
root@pmx0:~# uname -a
Linux pmx0 4.15.18-10-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-32 (Sat, 19 Jan 2019 10:09:37 +0100) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@pmx0:~# cat /etc/debian_version
9.8
root@pmx0:~# dpkg --list| grep drbd
ii  drbd-utils                           8.9.10-2                       amd64        RAID 1 over TCP/IP for Linux (user utilities)
root@pmx0:~# lsmod | grep drbd
drbd                  364544  1
lru_cache              16384  1 drbd
libcrc32c              16384  2 dm_persistent_data,drbd
root@pmx0:~# modinfo drbd
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.18-10-pve/kernel/drivers/block/drbd/drbd.ko
alias:          block-major-147-*
license:        GPL
version:        8.4.10
description:    drbd - Distributed Replicated Block Device v8.4.10
author:         Philipp Reisner <phil@linbit.com>, Lars Ellenberg <lars@linbit.com>
srcversion:     9A7FB947BDAB6A2C83BA0D4
depends:        lru_cache,libcrc32c
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           drbd
vermagic:       4.15.18-10-pve SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           allow_oos:DONT USE! (bool)
parm:           disable_sendpage:bool
parm:           proc_details:int
parm:           minor_count:Approximate number of drbd devices (1-255) (uint)
parm:           usermode_helper:string
```

**MOUNTS:**

```
root@pmx0:~# cat /proc/mounts
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=24679656k,nr_inodes=6169914,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=4940140k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mapper/pve-root / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=39,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=20879 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
sunrpc /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/intelSSD700G ext3 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs fuse.lxcfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0
/dev/fuse /etc/pve fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
10.0.0.15:/samba/shp /mnt/pve/bckNFS nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.0.0.15,mountvers=3,mountport=42772,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.15 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Finaly I have found the root cause of this problem!

At boot time the device mapper create mapping of logical volume on top of drbd device linked to the backing device, but it occure before drbd service startup. After this drbd cannot open exclusively the backing device resource. If I remove the mapping of lv device manualy, then drbd resource can be switch up.

Mapping can be remove by **`dmsetup remove <volume name>`** like the example below:

```
root@pmx0:~# lsblk
NAME                                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                       8:0    0 893.8G  0 disk
└─sda1                                    8:1    0 744.6G  0 part
  └─drbd--intel800--vg-vm--103--disk--0 253:2    0    80G  0 lvm
sdb                                       8:16   0 136.1G  0 disk
├─sdb1                                    8:17   0   512M  0 part
└─sdb2                                    8:18   0 135.6G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap                            253:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─pve-root                            253:1    0  33.8G  0 lvm  /
sdc                                       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdc1                                    8:33   0   1.8T  0 part
  └─drbd1                               147:1    0   1.8T  1 disk
sr0                                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
root@pmx0:~# dmsetup info -c
Name                                Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID
pve-swap                            253   0 L--w    2    1      0 LVM-upAG64GGzE9OLCOcDKvIwuNVzCg238v0xxrfApwyCQdQN3HBHnpPOhCSJe0eMQP3
pve-root                            253   1 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-upAG64GGzE9OLCOcDKvIwuNVzCg238v0kYEDRlWWy5IXJYWqB2Fzc117JT9w2004
drbd--intel800--vg-vm--103--disk--0 253   2 L--w    0    1      0 LVM-849ik4y1F5s9tZbA21R2TaiI9uK42SPp4waMZVBqzudKY3vXBxAV3IULRlEthcGW
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm up r0
open(/dev/sda1) failed: Device or resource busy
Operation canceled.
Command 'drbdmeta 0 v08 /dev/sda1 internal apply-al' terminated with exit code 20
root@pmx0:~# dmsetup remove drbd--intel800--vg-vm--103--disk--0
root@pmx0:~# dmsetup info -c
Name                           Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID
pve-swap                       253   0 L--w    2    1      0 LVM-upAG64GGzE9OLCOcDKvIwuNVzCg238v0xxrfApwyCQdQN3HBHnpPOhCSJe0eMQP3
pve-root                       253   1 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-upAG64GGzE9OLCOcDKvIwuNVzCg238v0kYEDRlWWy5IXJYWqB2Fzc117JT9w2004
root@pmx0:~# drbdadm attach r0
Marked additional 4948 MB as out-of-sync based on AL.
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
 0:r0/0  Connected Secondary/Secondary UpToDate/Diskless
```

After doing the same thing on the other node drbd disk status goes to UpToDate/UpToDate, can be set up to Primary/Primary by command drbdadm primary r0

```
root@pmx1:~# drbdadm attach r0
root@pmx1:~# drbd-overview
0:r0/0 SyncTarget Secondary/Secondary Inconsistent/UpToDate
[==>.................] sync'ed: 17.3% (4100/4948)M
root@pmx0:~# drbd-overview
0:r0/0 Connected Secondary/Secondary UpToDate/UpToDate
```

**Unfortunately this problem occurs on every reboot. The device mapper create the mapping again, and the same issue occurs.**

So drbd cannot set up resource on boot time. Didn't found any clear solution to solve this. The lvm filter in lvm.conf not affects this issue, only filters pv/vg/lv-s from scanning, but device mapper still create mapping at boot time. Unfortunately I cannot found solution to prevent it.

I have a workaround, but I dont like it.  Place the dmsetup remove  command on the drbd startup script at the begining of start) section. With this, the script remove the mapping before start drbd, but it needs the exact names of the lv volumes. Every time I create an new lv on the shared vg, it needs to put in the drbd startup script..

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems and error messages although my settings are a little different: The LVM logical volumes used for DRBD storage sit on top of a MD raid1. I do not understand what caused the problems (the system stopped and I had to do a cold restart), but the following commands helped me to find and resolve the "busy" problem.

[Code below from this blog](http://blog.roberthallam.org/2017/12/solved-logical-volume-is-used-by-another-device/comment-page-1/)

```
dmsetup info -c  => find Major and Minor of problematic device (253 and 2 in my case)

ls -la /sys/dev/block/253\:2/holders
```

contained a link to /dev/dm-9

The holders of all other drbd devices pointed to something like `drbd3 -> ../../drbd3`

Therefore (WARNING: I have no clue what damage that can cause. It just worked for me):

```
dmsetup remove /dev/dm-9

drbdadm up RESOURCE
```